# how to use sticky-top class in bootstrap 4 in grid

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, sticky

I trying to use `sticky-top` class in grid but its not working

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 sticky-top"> <!-- this grid should be sticky -->
          <div class="card text-left">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h4 class="card-title">Title</h4>
              <p class="card-text">Body</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" style="min-height:800px;">ssdfjosdfjsl</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">ssdfjosdfjsl</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

help me for fix this thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `align-items-start` to disable the stretch default alignment that make all the column equal in height thus there is no room to have a sticky behavior

```css
.container-fluid {
  border:1px solid;
}
.sticky-top {
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row align-items-start">
    <div class="col-sm-3 sticky-top"> <!-- this grid should be sticky -->
      <div class="card text-left">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title">Title</h4>
          <p class="card-text">Body</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="min-height:800px;">ssdfjosdfjsl</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">ssdfjosdfjsl</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With the borders you can clearly see the issue when we keep the default alignment:

```css
.container-fluid {
  border:1px solid;
}
.sticky-top {
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 sticky-top"> <!-- this grid should be sticky -->
      <div class="card text-left">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title">Title</h4>
          <p class="card-text">Body</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="min-height:800px;">ssdfjosdfjsl</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">ssdfjosdfjsl</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also keep the default alignment and make the card sticky

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3"> 
      <div class="card text-left sticky-top">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title">Title</h4>
          <p class="card-text">Body</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="min-height:800px;">ssdfjosdfjsl</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">ssdfjosdfjsl</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS add this:

```
.sticky-top{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

hope this will helps you.